# Insert into parent-child tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, parent-child

I have multiple level parent-child tables(GrandParent, Parent and Child, all many to one relation, one parent has multiple children, all children have one parent). Each has auto identity keys. Using C# and stored procedure, how to insert to them with foreign key constrains?
For example, the data to be inserted include multiple grand parents, each grad parent has multiple parents and each parent multiple children.

Sample data:

```
campus <- building <- office
```

Adding a few campuses and associated buildings/offices.

Comment: In what form do the items to be inserted exist in your system *prior* to the insert? How are they linked? If there was a way to pass *all* the items in a single call to an SP, would you be able to pass their links (like temporary IDs) along with the names and other properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function to retrieve the last inserted auto-increment ID:

```
DECLARE @new_parent_id INT

INSERT INTO MyParent(...) VALUES(...) -- your new parent data

SELECT @new_parent_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO MyChild(parent_id, ...) VALUES(@new_parent_id, ...)
```

Is this what you mean?

**EDIT**:

You can indeed pass in all your data at once with ADO.NET and SQL Server 2008 using Table Valued Parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

You could pass in your parent and child data as two tables to your stored procedure, then use a cursor to loop through your parents, inserting one, getting the generated ID, then inserting all its children before proceeding to the next parent.

This would probably be the most efficient solution, potentially requiring only a single call to the database, and if you have a large amount of data to insert, or if you think you can reuse this SP in other places in you solution, then this might be the way to go.

However, I think that inserting the records one-by-one from the client application is a cleaner and certainly a simpler way of achieving what you want.

Comment: If I insert multiple entries in MyParent, then I got a list of Ids, how do I link to the correct children for each Id?

Comment: After each insert you could use the above technique to store the generated ID in C#, which you can then refer back to when inserting the children.

Comment: Make sense. But I was wondering if I can use udtt(s) to insert a whole set in one sproc.

Comment: There is a question on these two tables (3 actually in my original question), there is no way to match them up first without the FK. Say we insert the first parent, then we don't know how many children belong to that...

Comment: I don't really understand your question then.  If there is generally no way for you to match children with their parents, then how can you EVER hope create a parent-child relationship in the database?  Perhaps you could add more detail to you question, showing how the data is structured in your C# application?

Comment: Maybe you could design the SP to take a single parent as the first parameter, and all of its children as the second?  Then call it multiple times for each parent?

Comment: You are right. This approach can work for only one parent. Then call multiple times.

Comment: + sample data in question. Maybe the alternative is using EF?

Comment: EF is certainly another approach worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really need here is a [database trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). You cannot enforce custom logic except for direct table referential integrity in a constraint. If you want custom logic (must have 2 parents, etc), then you will have to use a database trigger.

You can do something like this (pseudo code):

```
BEFORE INSERT
IF INSERT CAUSES MORE THAN 2 PARENTS
    DO NOT ALLOW INSERT
ELSE
    ALLOW INSERT
```